# How do I do something like redux's `connect()` - put props onto a component at declaration time?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I do this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        contacts: buildClientContacts(state)
    }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contacts)
```

I end up exporting a component like `Contacts`, except `connect` has put the `contacts` prop onto it for me (and used redux's `state` to build the `contacts` prop).

How can I do the same thing - declare a component based on another one, by adding props to it?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to put some props onto the component that have nothing to do with redux, instead of the mapToState shown in the code.

Something like this:

```
export default <Contacts mydata={somedata: data}>
```

(Obviously I can't put jsx there, but this is the sort of effect I want)

I could do this:

```
function mapStateToProps() {
    return {
        mydata: {somedata: data}
    }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contacts)
```

... but that's really abusing redux :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you need is a `Higher-Order Component (HOC)`. Please read more about this pattern [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). According to React docs:

> ... a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and
>   returns a new component.
>
> ```
> const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent);
> ```
>
> Whereas a component transforms props into UI, a higher-order component
>   transforms a component into another component.

Actually redux `connect` also returns HOC.

So you can create an `HOC` that will set required data as property on the `Contacts` component. In your case it would look like this:

```
function contactsWithData(WrappedComponent, data) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent mydata={data} {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
...
export default contactsWithData(Contacts, {somedata: true});
```